# The whole page become blank after redirecting with @header() in IE6

Tags: redirect, internet-explorer-6

It's a login page. After validating, the user is redirected to home page:

```
@header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
@header('Location: index.php');
@header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
@header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

But the page becomes blank if IE6! How? And it happens only for the first time; afterwards it'll work normally!

Comment: Why do you need all those other headers if you're just redirecting?  Why not just keep the one redirection line?  header('Location: index.php');

Comment: I copied it from anothoer project.

Comment: Additionally, it is good practice to halt execution after calling header(), so no other code executes. You can use die() or exit() to do that.

Comment: Actually, I usually write out a quick page with a link to follow, just incase something bad happens with the header() redirect. I agree that it is best to die as quickly as possible after calling to header() with a Location redirect though.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you suppressing the warnings/errors that might be happening? I'd say get rid of the `@` first, and then tell us what is really going on.

Answer (score 1):

header() won't work if there's any output already been sent.  This includes spaces, empty lines or whatever.  Make sure that there's strictly nothing being output before calling header.

Works:

```
<?php
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Does not work

```
 <?php
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

And remove the @, it eats up any useful info header tries to give you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect using javascript from client side:

Instead of :

```
@header('Location: index.php');
```

Client-side redirect:

```
echo "<script>document.location.replace('index.php');</script>";
```

Comment: Using the location header is orders of magnitude better. This will work in all browsers and user-agents, no matter what. Any HTTP library worth half it's salt recognises Location. Very few agents outside browsers will recognise the Javascript, and alot of the ones who do won't necessarily execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to a similar problem to yours for an hour or so. IE6 seems to have a problem with zipped content. Simply disabling mod_deflate on our server fixed the problem for IE6. Specifically version 6.0.29 appears to exhibit this bug.

Take a look at http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/moddeflate-and-ie6-bug